# Change dropdown styles

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I want to change my dropdown menu, I am working with wordpress. I want my dropdown menu to look like this

[image]

for the moment the only thing I have about css, I have never been very good in the front-end part

CSS:

```
.site-header #navbar {
  /*** hover effect ***/
}
.site-header #navbar li {
  position: relative;
}
.site-header #navbar > ul > li > a {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #222;
}
.site-header #navbar > ul .sub-menu {
  background-color: #051829;
  width: 220px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 130%;
  z-index: 10;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
.site-header #navbar > ul > li .sub-menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #072037;
}
.site-header #navbar > ul > li .sub-menu > li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.site-header #navbar > ul > li .sub-menu a {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-size: 0.86667rem;
  color: #c3bfbf;
  display: block;
  padding: 11px 15px;
}
.site-header #navbar > ul > li .sub-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #fdc900;
  color: #fff;
}
.site-header #navbar > ul > li > .sub-menu .sub-menu {
  left: 110%;
  top: 0;
}
.site-header #navbar > ul > li > .sub-menu > .menu-item-has-children > a {
  position: relative;
}
.site-header #navbar > ul > li > .sub-menu > .menu-item-has-children > a:before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f105";
  font-size: 15px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.site-header #navbar > ul > li:hover > .sub-menu {
  top: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.site-header #navbar .sub-menu > li:hover > .sub-menu {
  left: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

For the dropdown I'm using this [library](https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker) from github

This is how look like my dropdown

[image]

hope someone helpme

Comment: You can try different plugin for enabling the wide menu. Try searching for "Mega Menu".